# How to change the data source of a PIVOT table Using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am new to VBA and need to change the data source of the pivot to **'Sheet1'!$Q$4:$W$1940.** The pivot table is present on sheet1 Y1.
Please help with a working code, I have been searching on google but no luck!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the macro recorder yet?

Comment: No, recording the macro did not help

Answer (score 2):

### Change Pivot Table Data Source

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeDataSource() '
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim pCell As Range: Set pCell = ws.Range("Y3")
    Dim ptbl As PivotTable: Set ptbl = pCell.PivotTable
    ptbl.ChangePivotCache wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=ws.Range("Q4:W1940"), Version:=7)
End Sub
```

Comment: But I am getting an error like - subscript out of range error 1004 unable to get pivot table property of the range class. ( on the line :-  Dim ptb1 as pivottable : set ptbl = pCell.PivotTable) Can you please guide

Comment: What is pCell in your code above? Is it the cell that the Pivot table is supposed to be created in?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that since you are trying to set the range with code, you won't always know the # of rows.

But - you have to know *something* about the data to ensure it won't get errors. I am assuming that you know there will be data in cell Q4, and in your data set - there will always be a value in column Q.

```
Sub test()
    Dim intLastRow As Integer, intLastColumn As Integer
    
    intLastRow = Sheet1.Range("Q" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    intLastColumn = Sheet1.Cells(4, Application.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    If intLastRow <= 5 Then intLastRow = 5 'need to ensure there's a range to be slected
    If intLastColumn <= Sheet1.Range("Q4").Column Then intLastColumn = Sheet1.Range("Q4").Column 'Ensure there's at least one column to select
    
    Sheet1.PivotTables("pvtMyData").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase _
            , SourceData:=Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Range("Q4"), Sheet1.Cells(intLastRow, intLastColumn)) _
            , Version:=8)
End Sub
```

** note - when you click in a pivot table and then click on the "Pivot Table Analyze" Ribbon, there is an option at the top-left to name  your pivot table. In the example, I assume the name is "pvtMyData" - you can use the default name - e.g. "PivotTable5" but it might get confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This will list all sources for all pivot tables in your entire workbook.

```
Sub PivotSourceListAll()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsList As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim lPT As Long
Dim wsPT As Worksheet
Dim PTCount As Long
Dim strSD As String
On Error Resume Next

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

For Each wsPT In wb.Sheets
  If wsPT.PivotTables.Count Then
    PTCount = PTCount + 1
  End If
  If PTCount > 0 Then Exit For
Next wsPT

If PTCount = 0 Then
  MsgBox "No pivot tables in this workbook"
  Exit Sub
End If

Set wsList = Worksheets.Add
With wsList
  .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 3)).Value _
      = Array("Sheet", _
        "PivotTable", "Source Data")
End With
lPT = 2

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
  For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
    strSD = pt.SourceData
    If strSD = "" Then strSD = "N/A"
    With wsList
      .Range(.Cells(lPT, 1), _
        .Cells(lPT, 3)).Value _
          = Array(ws.Name, pt.Name, strSD)
    End With
    lPT = lPT + 1
    strSD = ""
  Next pt
Next ws

With wsList
  .Columns("A:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
  .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
End With

End Sub
```

Get that working, and it should take much, then you should easily be able to change the source/range of your pivot table to a different source/range.

https://www.contextures.com/excelpivottabledatasource.html

Comment: i do not need to list the data sources of pivot table, I need to change the data source

Comment: Just record a macro to change it. Learn from the cord that the macro recorder produces. Done.

Comment: I tried recording the macro, but it did not work/record it. i usually use record option. Can u try it at ur end once?